# Set JavaScript Object properties with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, javascript-objects

I have this JavaScript Object which I would like to set using Selenium.

```
var demoPlayResponse = {
 "winningPrizeIndex" : 1,
 "playMode"          : "NORMAL",
 "customerId"        : "pli",
 "gameVersion"       : "0-1-86",
 "gameId"            : "blue250k",
 "seed"              : 99
};
mws.GameModel.setPlayResponse(demoPlayResponse);
mws.GameModel.setGameMode(demoPlayResponse.playMode);
```

Is there any way to do this?

I tried this:

```
public void testMethod()
    {
        driver = BrowserFactory.getDriver("chrome", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver.get("http://jenkins.mws.com");

        WebDriverWait waitPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return getDemoPlayResponse()");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `execute()` [method](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html) of the Webdriver client in order to do the assignment in the browser. It's slightly hacky, but I think it would work something like this:

```js
client.execute(function() {
  var demoPlayResponse = {
   "winningPrizeIndex" : 1,
   "playMode"          : "NORMAL",
   "customerId"        : "pli",
   "gameVersion"       : "0-1-86",
   "gameId"            : "blue250k",
   "seed"              : 99
  };
  mws.GameModel.setPlayResponse(demoPlayResponse);
  mws.GameModel.setGameMode(demoPlayResponse.playMode);
});
```

Comment: I tested the code from the post. Do you know How I need to implement the client Object?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I'd look at the docs for your WebDriver library; there should be some explanation about how to get an instance of its client.